# How can i find the directory from where im running my program exe file?

Tags: c#, winforms

In my project \debug directory i have the program exe file for example:

test.exe

Now once i will run this test.exe from c:\
And in the second time i will copy the test.exe to d:\ and run it from there.

In my code i have this line:

```
string programFilesX86 = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86) + "\\Diagnostic Tool\\7z.dll";
```

Instead the program files x86 how can i get each the directory from where im running the exe file ?

Answer (score 1):

One way (sure fire way also in .Net CE) is

```
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(
  Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetModules()[0].FullyQualifiedName);
```

or

```
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(
  Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
```

This will prevent Shortcut's from setting the applications CurrentDirectory or StartupPath which could technically be different from it's execution path (ClickOne programs for example).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the running directory by doing:

```
Application.StartupPath
```

You can read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath.aspx)

Alternatively you can try `Environment.CurrentDirectory` but that may not yield you the results you want because of short cuts and other ways of getting to your file.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory.aspx

You can also do:

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

Or

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
```